# How to add a second toImageButton

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

In a python interactive plot using Plotly with the hoverable legend at the top: I would like to add a second `toImageButton` which downloads the plot as .svg (marked in orange) in addition to the button to download the plot as .png. Could also be a different button symbol if not possible otherways.

Is there any way how to do this?

example from: https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/

```
import plotly.express as px

config = {
  'toImageButtonOptions': {
    'format': 'svg',
    'filename': 'custom_image',
    'height': 500,
    'width': 700,
    'scale': 1 
  }
  
  ### something like this
  #,
  #'toImageButtonOptions': {
  #  'format': 'png', 
  #  'filename': 'custom_image',
  #  'height': 500,
  #  'width': 700,
  #  'scale': 1
  #}


}

fig = px.bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 1])

fig.show(config=config)
```

[image: how it should look like]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the plot and sorrounding UI now, and an edited image of where the new button should appear?